# HTML Agility Pack Parsing With Upper & Lower Case Tags?

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using the HTML Agility Pack to great effect, and am really impressed with it - However, I am selecting content like so

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerHtml
```

How to I deal with the following situation, with different documents?

```
<body>
<Body>
<BODY>
```

Will my code above only get the lower case versions?

Comment: What have you tried? Looks like something that can be tested in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Html Agility Pack handles HTML in a case insensitive way. It means it will *parse* BODY, Body and body the same way. It's by design since HTML is not case sensitive (XHTML is).

That said, when you use its XPATH feature, you *must* use tags written in lower case. It means the `"//body"` expression will match BODY, Body and body, and "//BODY" will match nothing.

Comment: @Mark - I actually am the author :-) I did that because XPATH is case sensitive (and the translate function is just so unpractical!) and HTML is not. I don't see any other nice solution?

Comment: I dunno...just lowercase everything if the document is HTML? But leave it if it's XHTML or XML? It's not such a big deal, just something to be aware of I guess :)

Comment: @Mark - The Html Agility Pack was designed for HTML, not for X(HT)ML, where you can safely use standard .NET classes. So for HTML, yes, it sort of "lowercase" everything, exactly.

Comment: Simon thanks for the clarification, got to say its an excellent library - Top job :)