# How to search both class and ID names in HTML code using same xpath query?

Tags: c#-4.0, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using the below code to search the class name `abc` in the `HTML` code:

```
nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' abc ')]");
```

Which is giving me correct result.

But if I want to search `ID` name `abc` instead of Class, the above code is not working.

Maybe the code which I am using contains `@clas`s word hence it is not working for ID names.

Is there any way to search both "Class" and "ID" names using same code?

Comment: Please give example XML code and expected output.

Comment: @Ranon, I believe the question is about HTML code. Possibly using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: XPath is on XML, so if he want's to use it oh HTML it must be valid XML (or he has to use some HTML parser which forms it to valid XML). Doesn't matter anyway, he should add some input.

Comment: Hi, I am using HtmlAgilityPack to get the HTML code part for which i am searching the class or ID name. I am not using any XML code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `ID` is different than `id`. HTML is case-insensitive, but XML is case-sensitive. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5779664/674700) from [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier), the author of [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

> That said, when you use its XPATH feature, you must use tags written
>   in lower case. It means the "//body" expression will match BODY, Body
>   and body, and "//BODY" will match nothing.

The same stands for `ID`.

Regarding the filter logic, you have to use the [`Logical-and` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256081.aspx):

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
    "//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' abc ')"+
        " and " +
        "contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@id), ' '), ' div1 ')]");
```

Or, simpler:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class=\"abc\" and @id=\"div1\"]");
```

But as a personal preference, if the context allows it, I would use `LINQ` to do it:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    .Where(i => 
        i.Attributes["class"] != null 
        && i.Id != null 
        && i.Attributes["class"].Value == "abc" 
        && i.Id == "div1");
```