# HTMLAgility Pack cannot find PageMap tag

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HTMLAgility pack to get information from HTML pages about articles.  I am able to find whatever I want throughout the document but for some reason I cannot find the PageMap object no matter what I do.  I created a test document to isolate just the PageMap and still no luck.

This is the test HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <PageMap>
            <DataObject type="document">
                <Attribute name="article_title">Test Title</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="article_publication_name">Test Publication Name</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="article_author">Test Authro | The Test</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="article_description">A test of test and test test test!</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="image_src">http://www.google.com</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="article_comments">0</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="article_date_original">10/31/2015</Attribute>
                <Attribute name="article_date_updated">10/31/2015</Attribute>
            </DataObject>
        </PageMap>


    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
string strPageHTML = File.ReadAllText(@"test.htm");

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(strPageHTML);

HtmlNode htmnArticle = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//PageMap");
tbMessagePreview.Text = htmnArticle.InnerHtml;
```

The live or test HTML both load fine but htmnArticle node is always null.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `//pagemap` (HtmlAgilityPack normalizes nodes to lower case - [HTML Agility Pack Parsing With Upper & Lower Case Tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776327/html-agility-pack-parsing-with-upper-lower-case-tags)):

```
HtmlNode htmnArticle = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//pagemap");
tbMessagePreview.Text = htmnArticle.InnerHtml;
```

Side note: looking at `doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml` helps to see how nodes are normalized.

Comment: TY, so easy.  I wish I had stumbled upon the other question in my searches, would have save a bunch of time.